# Deviantart API integration

Tags: android, deviantart-api

we are searching for someway to integrate our own deviant art galley in our android app.

**Below is our scenario explained**

1) we have a deviantart gallery with a lots of people daily using it.

2) So we want to know any possible way to integrate the same deviantart galley inside an android app, so that we can tell them to install that app to see our gallery.

3)we have found out deviantart provides some API to integrate deviantart data inside websites and applications, Below is the link https://www.deviantart.com/developers/ 
Is this API for integration inside android app?

4) Is there any other online free services which helps us to store image and data and fetch it inside android app?

5) If we create such an app, will it be possible to publish it through google play?

Answer (score 0):

2a) You can integrate a gallery in Android.

2b) You cannot block access to the gallery from the website. You can however recommend that they install the gallery app.

3) Yes, you can use the OAuth2 API for this application.

4) You do not need to store the images off of your app, DeviantArt is already doing that for you. Just make sure you read the DeviantArt Developers Terms of Service.

5) Yes, as long as you do not abuse DeviantArt's copyright, follow their Developers Terms of Service, and follow Google policies as well.